# Firebase Messaging Service, Error con Firebase, la aplicacion aparace instalada varias veces

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, push-notification, firebase-messaging

Cree un proyecto con `Firebase`, básicamente mi `app` esta recibiendo aplicaciones de prueba, llego un momento que mi dispositivo `android` no me dejaba reinstalar la `app`, aparecía un `Dialog` diciendo que había sido bloqueada la instalación a pesar de tener la configuración de seguridad de permitir instalaciones de orígenes desconocidos, aun así clickeaba instalar de todas formas cada vez que hacia modificaciones, investigue y la solución era aplicar este comando: `adb shell settings put global verifier_verify_adb_installs 0`, me dejo instalar la `app` sin problemas, pero en este momento cuando intento enviar `notificaciones` de prueba desde `Firebase`, me dice que hay 2, 3 y hasta 5 dispositivos utilizando ese `package` cuando solo lo estoy probando en mi dispositivo, intente borrar cache de mi `android`, Desinstalar manualmente, y al volver a instalar se me suma un usuario usando la `app` cuando voy a enviar la notificación y no solo eso, sino que la notificación ahora no llega, también probé invalidar caches de `android studio` y reiniciar y nada, reinicie mi dispositivo `android` y nada, no se me ocurre otra manera de solucionar, alguna sugerencia? gracias de antemano.

Acá el código que utilizo para la notificación con `Firebase`:

```
public class FirebaseServiceMessage extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Log.e("FIREBASE", Objects.requireNonNull(remoteMessage.getNotification()).getBody());

        int color = getResources().getColor(R.color.Standard);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_id_01";

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "My Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MAX);
            // Configure the notification channel.
            notificationChannel.setDescription("Informacion");
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            notificationChannel.getLightColor();
            notificationChannel.getSound();
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{0, 1000, 500, 1000});
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            assert notificationManager != null;
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        Intent stopped = new Intent(this,Main.class);

       /* Context: El contexto en que se crea el PendingIntent, nos lo facilita el método getBaseContext.
        RequestCode: En este caso no necesitamos ningún código de respuesta, por lo tanto pasamos 0.
        Intent: El Intent que se lanzará cuando se ejecute el PendingIntent.
        int: Banderas que indican el comportamiento del PendingIntent.
        Pasamos PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT que indica que se actualizará la información
        del PendingIntent en el caso de que se lance uno y ya existiera previamente.*/

        PendingIntent actionPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,stopped,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .addAction(R.drawable.simplebutton, "ACEPTAR", actionPendingIntent)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.drawable_icon_notification)
                .setContentTitle("Notificacion")
                .setColor(color)
                .setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/" + R.raw.beeep))
                .setContentText("Ha recibido una nueva notificacion")
                .setContentInfo("info");

        assert notificationManager != null;
        notificationManager.notify(/*notification id*/1, notificationBuilder.build());

    }
}
```

y acá la `clase` principal de mi `app`:

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Básicamente en mi actividad principal no hago nada, lo que me interesa es que reciba la notificación en `Firebase` que al comienzo normalmente lo hacia.

Asi registre la clase `FirebaseServiceMessage` mi `AndroidManifest`:

```
<service android:name=".FirebaseServiceMessage">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Comment: Sería bueno saber que código utilizas para registrar el dispositivo y como recibe las notificaciones.

Comment: @Jorgesys cierto, voy a editar la pregunta para colocarlo

Comment: Muchas gracias, de esta forma tendremos un mejor panorama de lo que sucede en realidad y podemos ayudarte a solucionar este problema @DavidVillegas saludos!